# How to provide additional JDBC properties for Google Cloud App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jdbc, quarkus

I'm trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database from Quarkus on Google App Engine. For this, additional JDBC properties "socketFactory" and "cloudSqlInstance" must be provided. But I can't figure out how to specify these in application.properties.

According to https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource, there is a propery "quarkus.datasource.jdbc.additional-jdbc-properties". But if I try to use it, connecting fails and in the logs I see:

> Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.datasource.jdbc.additional-jdbc-properties" was provided; it will be ignored;

I'm fairly sure that the required extensions are installed.

I tried several other properties like "quarkus.datasource.additional-jdbc-properties" mentioned [here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/6634/files/87c55f30d5890dc5f158920eb6dc05a5d32898b7), but without success. Now I've run out of ideas what to try. Is there any way to specify the required properties?

application.properties:

```
quarkus.package.type=uber-jar

# datasource configuration
quarkus.datasource.db-kind = postgresql
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url = jdbc:postgresql:///counter
quarkus.datasource.username = postgres
quarkus.datasource.password = <password>
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.additional-jdbc-properties=socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory,cloudSqlInstance=<project>:<region>:<instance>
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size=16

# drop and create the database at startup (use `update` to only update the schema)
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=drop-and-create
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.acme</groupId>
  <artifactId>getting-started</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus-plugin.version>1.10.2.Final</quarkus-plugin.version>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-universe-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>1.10.2.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>2.22.1</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
        <version>16.1.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus-plugin.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                    <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                  </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <properties>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Wich version of Quarkus do you use? It has been included in Quarkus 1.10.

Comment: 1.10.2.Final according to the POM (I used the "Getting started" app from the Quarkus website and extended it)

Comment: Could you paste your pom.xml? Thx

Comment: Added the pom.xml.

Comment: @RHa The issue is still open but they say that it will be released in 1.5.2 so I don't know the reason why it fails.
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/9985#issuecomment-643988727

Comment: Maybe it would be more suitable to open an issue on quarkusio side and see what they say about this matter.

Comment: @Luisao 1.10 contains the additional JDBC properties so we should be able to close the issue.
@RHa it should works, can you give us the configuration items you put inside `application.properties` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.additional-jdbc-properties.socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.additional-jdbc-properties.socketFactoryArg=<project>:<region>:<instance>
```

PS: You don't need to use strictly a SocketFactory to connect to a CloudSQL from GAE.